# how to have h1 inside a link in textile

Tags: textile

in textile:

to add a link we do: `"Link text":http://example.com`

to add h1 we do: `h1. Something`

how do you add an h1 inside a link? like `<a href="example.com"><h1>Link Text</h1></a>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading through a lot of [Textile's own help files](http://devzone.zend.com/node/textile), there's no way to put a header inside of a link. There is, however, a way to put a link inside of a header.

The reason is that Textile has two concepts of objects. "Block" objects and "phrase" objects. All phrases are contained within blocks, and any phrase can be contained within only one block. Blocks may not contain other blocks, and phrases may not contain blocks.

`h1` is a "block" element. `a` is a "phrase" element. Therefore `h1` can contain `a`, but `a` cannot contain `h1`. To do this you would type:

```
h1. "Link text":http://example.com
```